# Autofac Interface Ambiguity

Tags: interface, autofac, ambiguity

"The ambiguity, is in the box" - Monty Python.

Autofac is having a problem resolving an interface.   See attached [solution](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/909).

The Interface, IAmbiguous,  is defined in project ACommon.  It is implemented in project AInjectable.  The AInjectable project does not / cannot reference ACommon. The AInjectable project defines IAmbiguous as an existing item brought in with a file link.

The UI project calls ACommon Inject and  attempts to register the AInjectable assembly.  IAmbiguous is not ambiguous initially but after a builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes command it becomes "ambiguous in the namespace."  There is no error thrown when the container is built but the registration is not there.

Registration can be done "AsImplementedInterfaces" if Named and Keyed is not used.  But then there is no way to Resolve the registration because the service IAmbiguous is "ambiguous in the namespace."

Comment: So, what is the question here? Looks like everything works as expected, as it is pretty well explained in the answer in the link you provided. Those are different interfaces declared in different assemblies, and I'm not sure why you expect .NET or autofac to consider them as something related to each other.

Answer (score 1):

[This question was double-posted as an issue on Autofac.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/909) **It is not an Autofac problem.** I will copy/paste the answer from the issue in here; for future readers, if you want to see the repro solution, [go check out the full issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/909)

---

What you're doing by including the same interface in two different assemblies isn't something you should be doing. Note that by doing that, your `AInjectable` class is *not* implementing the interface from the `ACommon` project. It's implementing a *different but identically named interface*.

This sort of thing is a problem - having the same type (interface, class, whatever) name in two different assemblies. We even had a problem ([#782](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/782)) where we had a `System.SerializableAttribute` in Autofac as a shim for .NET Core. You really just can't do that.

You'll also see the same thing if you try to make a static extension method class that has the same namespace and name as some other static extension method class. Ambiguous references.

Without doing Reflection.Emit style code generation, you won't be able to declare an interface in one assembly ("Assembly A") and implement that interface in a different assembly ("Assembly B") without having Assembly B reference Assembly A. That's just how .NET works. What you're seeing is a manifestation of that when you use Autofac, but it's not caused by Autofac. It's caused by you doing something you shouldn't be doing in .NET.

The fix is to define your interfaces in a separate assembly that everyone implementing the interfaces can reference. (Or you can try to dynamically generate code using Reflection.Emit or Roslyn or something, but that's waaaay harder.)